# Works on WAMP but not on remote server

Tags: php, mysql

I have WAMP (PHP Version 5.5.12) running on my machine. My program works on WAMP but when I run program on remote server (PHP Version 5.4.32) I get following error:

> Array ( [0] => 42S22 [1] => 1054 [2] => Unknown column 'address' in
>   'field list' )

I am trying to transfer details from a form to a database. I don't know if the problem is related to following input on form:

```
Address:<br> <textarea name="address" rows="3" cols="25" WRAP="hard"><?php echo escape(Input::get('address')); ?> </textarea>
```

Input::get($item) returns $_POST[$item] if it is set. Other entries are like:

```
Last name: <input type="text" name="last_name" value="<?php echo escape(Input::get('last_name')); ?>">
```

and do not create problems. I have tried using print_r($e->errorInfo()); in my catch statement:

catch(Exception $e)
   { die($e->getMessage());
   }

but that doesn't work. I don't know if I am using it correctly or not. Could someone offer a suggestion. I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 0):

I think you haven't updated your database. You try to fetch a columns from your database which doesn't exist.

So check where you have a field named *address* and check if the field is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks for the replies.

> QI think you haven't updated your database. You try to fetch a columns
>   from your database which doesn't exist.

I have checked that and that's not the problem. I think the problem lies with the following functions:

```
public function insert($table, $fields = array())
   { if(count($fields)) //true if $fields holds data
     { $keys = array_keys($fields);

       $values = '';  //to put inside query

       $x = 1;

      foreach($fields as $field)
      { $values .= '?';
        if($x < count($fields))
        { $values .= ', ';
        }
        $x++;
      }
   $sql = "INSERT INTO {$table} (`".implode('`, `', $keys) . "`) VALUES({$values})";
      if(!$this->query($sql, $fields)->error())
      { return true;
      }
     }
     return false;
   }

  public function query($sql, $darams = array())
  { 
    $this->_error = false;   //reset error
    if($this->_query = $this->_pdo->prepare($sql))
    { $x = 1;
      if(count($darams))
      { foreach($darams as $param)
        { $this->_query->bindValue($x, $param);
          $x++;
        }
      }
      if($this->_query->execute())
      { $this->_results = $this->_query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        $this->_count = $this->_query->rowCount();
      }
      else      //an error has occured in SQL query
      { $this->_error = true;
      }
    }
    return $this;
  }
```

insert() through, $values .= '?'; is creating ? as the values for the fields. query() through bindValue() is giving values to those fields to be inserted. I have a feeling address, which allows for new lines, spaces and commas, is causing problems when it comes to the binding. I wonder if you agree and if so have you a solution?